# How can I tell, with something like objdump, if an object file has been built with -fPIC?

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, objdump, fpic

How can I tell, with something like `objdump`, if an object file has been built with `-fPIC`?

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/test-whether-linux-binary-is-compiled-as-position-independent-code

Answer (score 84):

The answer depends on the platform. On most platforms, if output from

```
readelf --relocs foo.o | egrep '(GOT|PLT|JU?MP_SLOT)'
```

is empty, then either `foo.o` was not compiled with `-fPIC`, or `foo.o` doesn't contain any code where `-fPIC` matters.

Comment: I tested my PIC/no-PIC objects and this test didn't work. In fact --reloc listed nothing.

Comment: @teambob Sorry, `objdump` doesn't understand `--relocs` flag, `readelf` does.

Comment: Now that you have edited it, it works and is a nice easy test. I am voting it up for you.

Comment: This is not a very helpful test. This doesn't prove anything if it is not empty. Consider a shared library consisting of 2 object files. One object file is compiled with -fPIC, another is compiled without. The output won't be empty, but the library is not position independent.

Comment: @Vanuan The test doesn't work for shared libraries, true. But the question was about object files, not shared libraries.

Comment: @Employed Russian I that case the question is pointless. PIC is very common (if not a must) for shared libraries. Again, if there is no output, this doesn't mean that the file is compiled without -fPIC. You would want to know if something is compiled without -fPIC to fix it. I think, the question meaning is "How to be sure that a shared library is position independent?".

Comment: I can't even get a shared library from object files compiled without -fPIC. ld produces an error : relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Comment: Do you mind explaining why this test makes sense, or what the reasoning behind it is? What is one grepping for? Why won't those things be found in something without -fPIC?

Comment: Doesn't even work for object files. Consider compiling with `-m32` still produces the same output here as compiling with `fPIC`. This isn't sufficient.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out if an object was not compiled with `-fPIC` or it doesn't contain any code where `-fPIC` matters?

Answer (score 18):

I just had to do this on a PowerPC target to find which shared object (.so) was being built without -fPIC.  What I did was run **readelf -d libMyLib1.so** and look for TEXTREL.  If you see TEXTREL, one or more source files that make up your .so were not built with -fPIC.  You can substitute **readelf** with **elfdump** if necessary.

E.g.,

```
[user@host lib]$ readelf -d libMyLib1.so | grep TEXT   # Bad, not -fPIC
 0x00000016 (TEXTREL)
[user@host lib]$ readelf -d libMyLib2.so | grep TEXT   # Good, -fPIC
[user@host lib]$
```

And to help people searching for solutions, the error I was getting when I ran my executable was this:

```
root@target:/# ./program: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libMyLi
b1.so:  R_PPC_REL24 relocation at 0x0fc5987c for symbol 'memcpy' out of range
```

I don't know whether this info applies to all architectures.

Source: [blogs.oracle.com/rie](https://blogs.oracle.com/rie/entry/my_relocations_don_t_fit)

Answer (score 3):

I assume, what you really want to know is whether or not a shared library is composed from object files compiled with -fPIC.

As already mentioned, if there are TEXTRELs, then -fPIC was not used.

There is a great tool called scanelf which can show you the symbols that caused .text relocations.

More information can be found at [HOWTO Locate and Fix .text Relocations TEXTRELs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/Textrels_Guide).

Answer (score 2):

```
readelf -a *.so | grep Flags
  Flags:                             0x50001007, noreorder, pic, cpic, o32, mips32
```

This should work most of the time.

Comment: This looks so simple, but the library in front of me is relocatable, has plenty of R_386_JUMP_SLOT entries in its .rel.plt table, but has 0x0 for Flags. Perhaps it only works on mips32.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work on aarch64

Answer (score 2):

-fPIC means that code will be able to execute in addresses different form the address that was compile for.

To do it , disasambler will look like this....

```
call get_offset_from_compilation_address
get_offset_from_compilation_address: pop ax
sub ax, ax , &get_offset_from_compilation_address
```

now in ax we have an offset that we need to add to any access to memory.

```
load bx, [ax + var_address}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to distinguish whether your program is generated wit -fPIC option:

provided that your code has -g3 -gdwarf-2 option enabled when compiling.

other gcc debug format may also contains the macro info:

Note the following $'..' syntax is assumes bash

```
echo $' main() { printf("%d\\n", \n#ifdef __PIC__\n__PIC__\n#else\n0\n#endif\n); }' | gcc -fPIC -g3 
-gdwarf-2 -o test -x c -

readelf --debug-dump=macro ./test | grep __PIC__
```

such a method works because gcc manual declares that if -fpic is used, **PIC** is defined to 1, and
if -fPIC used, **PIC** is 2.

The above answers by checking the GOT is the better way. Because the prerequest of -g3 -gdwarf-2 I guess seldom being used.

Answer (score 0):

From *The Linux Programming Interface*:

> On Linux/x86-32, it is possible to create a shared library using
> modules compiled without the `–fPIC` option. However, doing so loses
> some of the benefits of shared libraries, since pages of program text
> containing position-dependent memory references are not shared across
> processes. On some architectures, it is impossible to build shared
> libraries without the `–fPIC` option.
>
> In order to determine whether an existing object file has been
> compiled with the `–fPIC` option, we can check for the presence of the
> name `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_` in the object file’s symbol table, using
> either of the following commands:
>
> ```
> $ nm mod1.o | grep _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
> $ readelf -s mod1.o | grep _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
> ```
>
> Conversely, if either of the following equivalent commands yields any
> output, then the specified shared library includes at least one object
> module that was not compiled with `–fPIC`:
>
> ```
> $ objdump --all-headers libfoo.so | grep TEXTREL
> $ readelf -d libfoo.so | grep TEXTREL
> ```

**However, neither above quoting nor any answer of this question works for x86_64.**

What I've observed on my x86_64 Ubuntu machine is that, whether specifying `-fPIC` or not, it would generate fPIC `.o`. That is

```
gcc -g -Wall -c -o my_so.o my_so.c // has _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
gcc -g -Wall -fPIC -c -o my_so_fpic.o my_so.c // has _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_

readelf -s my_so.o > 1.txt && readelf -s my_so_fpic > 2.txt && diff 1.txt 2.txt
```

has no difference and both `my_so.o` and `my_so_fpic.o` can be used to create a shared library.

In order to generate non fpic object file, I found a gcc flag called `-fno-pic` in the first comment of [How to test whether a Linux binary was compiled as position independent code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/how-to-test-whether-a-linux-binary-was-compiled-as-position-independent-code) .

This works,

```
gcc -g —Wall -fno-pic -c -o my_so_fnopic.o my_so.c // no _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
```

and

```
gcc -g -Wall -shared -o libdemo.so my_so_fnopic.o
```

gives error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: my_so_fnopic.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

can not create a shared library with non pic `.o`.