# What is the -fPIE option for position-independent executables in gcc and ld?

Tags: gcc, linker, aslr, position-independent-code

How will it change the code, e.g. function calls?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

PIE is to support [address space layout randomization (ASLR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) in executable files.

Before the PIE mode was created, the program's executable could not be placed at a random address in memory, only position independent code (PIC) dynamic libraries could be relocated to a random offset. It works very much like what PIC does for dynamic libraries, the difference is that a Procedure Linkage Table (PLT) is not created, instead PC-relative relocation is used.

After enabling PIE support in gcc/linkers, the body of program is compiled and linked as position-independent code. A dynamic linker does full relocation processing on the program module, just like dynamic libraries. Any usage of global data is converted to access via the Global Offsets Table (GOT) and GOT relocations are added.

PIE is well described in [this OpenBSD PIE presentation](http://www.openbsd.org/papers/nycbsdcon08-pie/).

Changes to functions are shown [in this slide](http://www.openbsd.org/papers/nycbsdcon08-pie/mgp00004.html) (PIE vs PIC).

> x86 pic vs pie
>
> Local global variables and functions are optimized in pie
>
> External global variables and functions are same as pic

and in [this slide](http://www.openbsd.org/papers/nycbsdcon08-pie/mgp00005.html) (PIE vs old-style linking)

> x86 pie vs no-flags (fixed)
>
> Local global variables and functions are similar to fixed
>
> External global variables and functions are same as pic

Note, that PIE may be incompatible with `-static`

Comment: Also in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#Position-independent_executables

Comment: Why -pie and -static are compatible on ARM and are NOT compatible at x86? My SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082959/gcc-static-and-pie-are-incompatible-for-x86

Comment: Yes. it is really good answer. ASLR meaning it just load on random memory.  that random memory doesn't means Phsyical Memory. It also use virtual memory. if you use -fno-pie and -no-pie option at gcc, and then use objdump -d. then you can check every program start 0x800. but if you use just pie option, then you check program start low address. that address is different when loaded on memory by process loader.

Answer (score 105):

**Minimal runnable example: GDB the executable twice**

For those that want to see some action, let's see ASLR work on the PIE executable and change addresses across runs:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("hello");
}
```

main.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
for pie in no-pie pie; do
  exe="${pie}.out"
  gcc -O0 -std=c99 "-${pie}" "-f${pie}" -ggdb3 -o "$exe" main.c
  gdb -batch -nh \
    -ex 'set disable-randomization off' \
    -ex 'break main' \
    -ex 'run' \
    -ex 'printf "pc = 0x%llx\n", (long  long unsigned)$pc' \
    -ex 'run' \
    -ex 'printf "pc = 0x%llx\n", (long  long unsigned)$pc' \
    "./$exe" \
  ;
  echo
  echo
done
```

For the one with `-no-pie`, everything is boring:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401126: file main.c, line 4.

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello");
pc = 0x401126

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello");
pc = 0x401126
```

Before starting execution, `break main` sets a breakpoint at `0x401126`.

Then, during both executions, `run` stops at address `0x401126`.

The one with `-pie` however is much more interesting:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1139: file main.c, line 4.

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello");
pc = 0x5630df2d6139

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello");
pc = 0x55763ab2e139
```

Before starting execution, GDB just takes a "dummy" address that is present in the executable: `0x1139`.

After it starts however, GDB intelligently notices that the dynamic loader placed the program in a different location, and the first break stopped at `0x5630df2d6139`.

Then, the second run also intelligently noticed that the executable moved again, and ended up breaking at `0x55763ab2e139`.

`echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` ensures that ASLR is on (the default in Ubuntu 17.10): [How can I temporarily disable ASLR (Address space layout randomization)? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318315/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization).

`set disable-randomization off` is needed otherwise GDB, as the name suggests, turns off ASLR for the process by default to give fixed addresses across runs to improve the debugging experience: [Difference between gdb addresses and "real" addresses? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061475/difference-between-gdb-addresses-and-real-addresses).

**`readelf` analysis**

Furthermore, we can also observe that:

```
readelf -s ./no-pie.out | grep main
```

gives the actual runtime load address (pc pointed to the following instruction 4 bytes after):

```
64: 0000000000401122    21 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
```

while:

```
readelf -s ./pie.out | grep main
```

gives just an offset:

```
65: 0000000000001135    23 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 main
```

By turning ASLR off (with either `randomize_va_space` or `set disable-randomization off`), GDB always gives `main` the address: `0x5555555547a9`, so we deduce that the `-pie` address is composed from:

```
0x555555554000 + random offset + symbol offset (79a)
```

TODO where is 0x555555554000 hard coded in the Linux kernel / glibc loader / wherever? [How is the address of the text section of a PIE executable determined in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343596/how-is-the-address-of-the-text-section-of-a-pie-executable-determined-in-linux)

**Minimal assembly example**

Another cool thing we can do is to play around with some assembly code to understand more concretely what PIE means.

We can do that with a Linux x86_64 freestanding assembly hello world:

main.S

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
asm_main_after_prologue:
    /* write */
    mov $1, %rax   /* syscall number */
    mov $1, %rdi   /* stdout */
    mov $msg, %rsi  /* buffer */
    mov $len, %rdx /* len */
    syscall

    /* exit */
    mov $60, %rax   /* syscall number */
    mov $0, %rdi    /* exit status */
    syscall
msg:
    .ascii "hello\n"
len = . - msg
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/39de6f6abf45c881ff5fc4f490fd225cadeba78c/userland/arch/x86_64/freestanding/linux/hello.S)

and it assembles and runs fine with:

```
as -o main.o main.S
ld -o main.out main.o
./main.out
```

However, if we try to link it as PIE with (`--no-dynamic-linker` is required as explained at: [How to create a statically linked position independent executable ELF in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664494/how-to-create-a-statically-linked-position-independent-executable-elf-in-linux)):

```
ld --no-dynamic-linker -pie -o main.out main.o
```

then link will fail with:

```
ld: main.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output
```

Because the line:

```
mov $msg, %rsi  /* buffer */
```

hardcodes the message address in the `mov` operand, and is therefore not position independent.

If we instead write it in a position independent way:

```
lea msg(%rip), %rsi
```

then PIE link works fine, and GDB shows us that the executable does get loaded at a different location in memory every time.

The difference here is that `lea` encoded the address of `msg` relative to the current PC address due to the `rip` syntax, see also: [How to use RIP Relative Addressing in a 64-bit assembly program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250277/how-to-use-rip-relative-addressing-in-a-64-bit-assembly-program)

We can also figure that out by disassembling both versions with:

```
objdump -S main.o
```

which give respectively:

```
e:   48 c7 c6 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rsi
e:   48 8d 35 19 00 00 00    lea    0x19(%rip),%rsi        # 2e <msg>

000000000000002e <msg>:
  2e:   68 65 6c 6c 6f          pushq  $0x6f6c6c65
```

So we see clearly that `lea` already has the full correct address of `msg` encoded as current address + 0x19.

The `mov` version however has set the address to `00 00 00 00`, which means that a relocation will be performed there: [What do linkers do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322911/what-do-linkers-do/33690144#33690144) The cryptic `R_X86_64_32S` in the `ld` error message is the actual type of relocation that was required and which cannot happen in PIE executables.

Another fun thing that we can do is to put the `msg` in the data section instead of `.text` with:

```
.data
msg:
    .ascii "hello\n"
len = . - msg
```

Now the `.o` assembles to:

```
e:   48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 15 <_start+0x15>
```

so the RIP offset is now `0`, and we guess that a relocation has been requested by the assembler. We confirm that with:

```
readelf -r main.o
```

which gives:

```
Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x160 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000011  000200000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .data - 4
```

so clearly `R_X86_64_PC32` is a PC relative relocation that `ld` can handle for PIE executables.

This experiment taught us that the linker itself checks the program can be PIE and marks it as such.

Then when compiling with GCC, `-pie` tells GCC to generate position independent assembly.

But if we write assembly ourselves, we must manually ensure that we have achieved position independence.

In ARMv8 aarch64, the position independent hello world can be achieved with the [ADR instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906688/what-are-the-semantics-of-adrp-and-adrl-instructions-in-arm-assembly/54042899#54042899).

**How to determine if an ELF is position independent?**

Besides just running it through GDB, some static methods are mentioned at:

- executable: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/how-to-test-whether-a-linux-binary-was-compiled-as-position-independent-code/435038#435038
- library: [How can I tell, with something like objdump, if an object file has been built with -fPIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340402/how-can-i-tell-with-something-like-objdump-if-an-object-file-has-been-built-wi)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Hi Ciro! Can you create separate question for ASLR-off pie-on start address and link it here?

Comment: @osgx Done. Do you already know or are you going to dig it up on the fly? :-) While you are at it, it would be cool to explain how the Linux kernel / dyn loader determines if something has PIE or not: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/how-to-test-whether-a-linux-binary-was-compiled-as-position-independent-code

Comment: I don't know already, but I know that it should be digged from rtld of glibc - glibc/elf https://github.com/lattera/glibc/tree/master/elf (if interpreter is still ld-linux.so). Three years ago Basile was not sure about 0x55555555 also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856044, but that question was about starting address of ld.so itself, so dig into kernel's [fs/binfmt_elf.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18-rc4/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c) or readelf/objdump and linker scripts.

Comment: Informative answer. First half just enough for me. How do I also show the address when the break hits in gdb? It didn't show on my side Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @haxpor hi, when you run `main.sh` you don't see `pc = 0x401126` on the output, coming from `-ex 'printf "pc = 0x%llx\n", (long  long unsigned)$pc'`? I've just retested on Ubuntu 21.04 and it was there.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆再教育营六四事件法轮功郝海东 I mean for address shown when you add a new breakpoint within gdb. Anyway, my apology for that. I carefully tested it again, and this time I saw it. Thanks!