# Using RIP-relative addressing in OSX x64 assembly

Tags: macos, assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64

I was trying to make a basic `printf` example in x86-64 assembly code for OSX, here's my first version:

```
section .data
msg db 'hello', 0Ah

section .text
extern _printf

global _main
_main:
  sub rsp, 8

  mov rdi, msg
  mov rax, 0
  call _printf

  add rsp, 8

  ret
```

So this code is moving the absolute address of `msg` into `rdi` for the first argument to `_printf`, and gcc then complains about the lack of position-independent code. The binary still works though:

```
→ nasm -f macho64 new.asm && gcc -m64 -o new new.o && ./new
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _main from new.o. To fix this warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
hello
```

So when I change the code to use RIP-relative addressing, using the `[rel ...]` nasm syntax, the warning disappears but the executable now seg faults:

```
section .data
msg db 'hello', 0Ah

section .text
extern _printf

global _main
_main:
  sub rsp, 8

  mov rdi, [rel msg]
  mov rax, 0
  call _printf

  add rsp, 8

  ret
```

And when I compile and run it:

```
→ nasm -f macho64 new.asm && gcc -m64 -o new new.o && ./new
zsh: segmentation fault  ./new
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: Same for GAS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250277/how-to-use-rip-relative-addressing-in-a-64-bit-assembly-program

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the original `mov rdi, msg` loaded the memory address of `msg` into `rdi` at assemble time.

When it was changed to `mov rdi, [rel msg]`, this produced code which used the value in `msg` as the relative address, as seen when debugging:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00000a6f6c6c6568
```

Notice how the address contains the bytes from `msg`, `0x00000a<olleh>`.

The correct solution is to use the `lea` instruction to load the effective RIP-relative address of `msg` at runtime, like so:

```
lea rdi, [rel msg]
```

Comment: ... and zero-terminate your string!