# C++: Inline ASM improper operand type LEA RDI, char[]

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm trying to integrate some opensource code that's using inline assembly into my application. Compiling throws C2415 improper operand type, and I can't find any information on what might be wrong and how to fix it.

The original application that the code is from came compiled alongside source code and runs fine, though I don't know what compiler was used.

Code excerpt:

```
__asm {
    push rax
    push rbx
    push rcx
    push rdx
    push rdi
    lea  rdi, variable
    ...
}
```

The error occurs on LEA command, variable is char[100]

Comment: Post code that will *actually* reproduce this error when we try it ourselves.

Comment: The source operand of `lea` needs to be a memory address, i.e. something of the form `[register + stride * index]`.

Comment: You also forgot to mention what compiler you are using.

Comment: Try this = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339972/using-rip-relative-addressing-in-osx-x64-assembly