# Push on 64-bit intel osx

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64

I want to push a 64-bit address on stack as below,

```
__asm("pushq $0x1122334455667788");
```

But I get compilation error and I can only push in following way,

```
__asm("pushq $0x11223344");
```

Can someone help me understand my mistake?

I am new to assembly, so please excuse me if my question sounds stupid.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

x86-64 has some interesting quirks, which aren't obvious even if you're familiar with 32-bit x86...

1. Most instructions can only take a 32-bit immediate value, which is sign-extended to 64 bits if used in a 64-bit context.  (The instruction encoding stores only 32 bits.)

   This means that you can use `pushq` for immedate values in the range `0x0` - `0x7fffffff` (i.e. positive signed 32-bit values which are sign-extended with 0 bits) or `0xffffffff80000000` - `0xffffffffffffffff`) (i.e. negative signed 32-bit values which are sign-extended with 1 bits).  But you cannot use values outside this range (as they cannot be represented in the instruction encoding).
2. `mov` is a special case: there is an encoding which takes a full 64-bit immediate operand.  Hence Daniel's answer (which is probably your best bet).
3. If you *really* don't want to corrupt a register, you could use multiple pushes of smaller values.  However, the obvious thing of pushing two 32-bit values won't work.  In the 64-bit world, `push` will work with a 64 bit operand (subject to point 1 above, if it's an immediate constant), or a 16 bit operand, but not a 32 bit operand (even `pushl %eax` is not valid).  So the best you can do is 4 16-bit pushes:

   `pushw $0x1122; pushw $0x3344; pushw $0x5566; pushw $0x7788`

Comment: Comment to point #3: `subq $8, %rsp; movl $0x55667788, (%rsp); movl $11223344, 4(%rsp)` would work too.

Comment: @Jester: pushl $0x55667788; movl $11223344, 4(%rsp) ?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: No, `pushl` is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-push-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-specif) [encodeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305965/does-each-push-instruction-push-a-multiple-of-8-bytes-on-x64) in 64-bit mode.  You want `pushq` (aka `push`) with a sign-extended 32-bit immediate, then `movl $high, 4(%rsp)` to overwrite the high half.

Answer (score 9):

Your best bet would be to do something like this.

```
movq $0x1122334455667788, %rax
pushq %rax
```

Replace `%rax` with any other 64-bit register you find appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

There is no single instruction capable of taking a 64-bit immediate value and pushing that onto the stack.

Answer (score 5):

from [how to use rip relative addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250277/how-to-use-rip-relative-addressing-in-a-64-bit-assembly-program/13356588)

```
pushq my_const(%rip)
...
my_const: .quad 1122334455667788
```