# asm64 write system call: non-adjacent memory?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

I have this little program written in x64 assembly:

```
xor    rdx,rdx
push   rdx            ;null terminator
push   0x41414141     ;AAAA
push   0x45454545     ;EEEE
mov    rsi,rsp        ;pointer to the string
mov    rdi,1          ;output file: stdout
mov    rdx,8          ;buffer size 8
mov    rax,1          ;write syscall
syscall
```

As you can see, I push eight bytes to the stack and when I call write with buffer size 8, I am expecting to see `EEEEAAAA` but the output is `EEEE`. However, when I set the buffer size `rdx` to 12, I can see the full string `EEEEAAAA`. What is between those four-byte blocks? Aren't they ought to be adjacent?

Comment: Check this one -- you can't push 32-bit constants or registers in x64 mode -- only 16-bit and 64-bit operand sizes are supported. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351363/push-on-64bit-intel-osx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each push writes 8 bytes, since that is the stack size in 64 bit mode. The immediate in the instruction is sign extended to 64 bits, see the instruction set reference: *If the source operand is an immediate of size less than the operand size, a sign-extended value is pushed on the stack.*

As such, your stack looks like (from `rsp` upwards):

```
0x0000000045454545 ; EEEE sign extended to 64 bits
0x0000000041414141 ; AAAA sign extended to 64 bits
0x0000000000000000 ; NULL terminator
```

As workaround you can do:

```
xor rdx, rdx
push rdx
mov rax, 0x4141414145454545
push rax
mov    rsi,rsp        ;pointer to the string
mov    rdi,1          ;output file: stdout
mov    rdx,8          ;buffer size 8
mov    rax,1          ;write syscall
syscall
```

Comment: Pushing the string as 2 byte blocks also works, as @Aki Suihkonen said.

Comment: Pushing 2 byte blocks is inefficient and also temporarily messes up stack alignment which might be an issue under some circumstances.