# 64-bit mode does not support 32-bit PUSH and POP instructions

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

NASM returns an error like: "instruction not supported in 64-bit mode"
(Or with YASM, `invalid size for operand 1`)

The subject instructions are `pop ecx` and `push ecx`.
What can I use instead of them or is there an other way to fix this issue?

Comment: show your code, or the question will be invalid. `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Answer (score 31):

*The general idea* is that you normally push and pop full registers, i.e. 64-bit registers in 64-bit mode.  `push`'s default operand-size is 64-bit, and 32-bit operand-size is not available.  [Does each PUSH instruction push a multiple of 8 bytes on x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305965/does-each-push-instruction-push-a-multiple-of-8-bytes-on-x64/40312390#40312390) (yes, unless you specifically use a 16-bit push, but 32-bit isn't available).

You cannot push a 32 bit register in 64 bit mode; instead, you can push and pop the whole 64 bit register that contains a 32-bit value you want, so that's `push rax` instead of `push eax`. The same holds for memory references - you can `push qword ptr[rax]`, but not `push dword ptr[rax]`.

*But*: even in 64 bit mode you can still push:

- 8 or 32 bit immediates sign extended to 64; this is generally handled automatically by your assembler as an optimization (if you do `push 1` it will encode it with the most compact encoding, which will be `6A01`, i.e. with an *imm8* operand).  It's [always a 64-bit push unless you explicitly specify `push word 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-pushes-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-spec), regardless of what width of immediate the assembler picks.
- the `fs` and `gs` segment registers  *but not* the `cs`, `ds`, `es`, `ss` registers (which aren't important in 64-bit mode, and can only be read with [`mov`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html), not `push`, freeing up those push/pop opcode for potential future use).

  As an exception, segment registers are either *zero*-extended or pushed on the stack with a 16-bit move (i.e. the other 48 bit on the stack are left unmodified); this isn't really much of a problem, since `pop fs` and `pop gs` just discard these extra bits.

You can emulate a `push imm64` with `push low32` / `mov dword [rsp+4], high32`.  Or with `mov r64, imm64` / `push r64`; `mov` to register (not memory) is the only x86-64 instruction that can take a 64-bit immediate.

---

With 16-bit operand-size (a `66h` prefix), you can do a 16-bit push which adjusts RSP by 2 instead of 8.  But normally don't do this because it will misalign the stack until you do a 16-bit pop or otherwise correct it.

- 16 bit registers (`push ax`) and memory references (`push word ptr[rax]`);
- 8-bit sign-extended or 16 bit immediates.  `push word 123`

---

8-bit registers can't be pushed in any mode (except as part of a wider register), and 32-bit push/pop aren't available in 64-bit mode, [even with a `REX.W=0` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-pushes-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-spec).

Comment: Besides the fact that you can push r/m16 and r/m64 but not r/m32, the fact that you can push imm8, imm16 and imm32 but not imm64 is weird too. And you can't push CS,DS,ES or SS, but you can push FS and GS. Pretty inconsistent, IMO.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: it *is* quite inconsistent, although there's a bit of method in this madness. Not being able to push an *imm64* is vaguely coherent with the rest of the instruction set - the only instruction that accepts an *imm64* that I know of is `mov r64, imm64` (actually, it's the only match for *imm64* in the whole instruction set description in Intel manuals). The segment registers besides *fs* and *gs* are no longer used in 64 bit mode, so it's unsurprising that they cannot be pushed.

Comment: I understand the "method behind the madness". But it gets quite confusing, at times. Especially the fact you can push/pop 16 bit but not 32 bit items.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, The reason you can't `push eax` in x64 is that the encoding for `push r64` in x64 is the same as the encoding for `push r32` in x86. I.e. `push reg` means `push native_register_size`. Making it otherwise would require extending the instruction-set. and God knows x64 has more than enough instructions already.  The 16/8 bit push already existed, so these are retained as legacy.

Comment: @Johan: I understood that, when looking at the instruction tables with the opcodes. But it gets more and more confusing, no matter the reason for it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: agreed; I found it confusing that `push r32` isn't encodeable in x86-64 mode.  I thought the wording of the text in Intel's manual implied that `REX.W=0` could override the operand size down to 32-bit instead of the default 64, but the table (and testing on real CPUs!) indicates that's not the case; see the footnote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-pushes-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-spec) I wrote to get to the bottom of the situation.