# Understanding the pop instruction in assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I am a student studying computer systems for the first time (w/ Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective). We are working on assembly and I am starting to understand command suffixes for x86_64 such as using `leaq` in something like:

`leaq  (%rsp, %rdx), %rax`

However, I am failing to understand using a suffix for `pop`. For example, using the same logic, it would make sense to me that we'd use `popl` for something like:

`popl  %edi`

But, in the text and other examples online, I just see:

`pop  %edi`

What is the difference? is `popl` even valid? Just looking for a little more insight. Anything helps, thank you.

Comment: It's not valid. Consult the instruction set reference to see the allowed forms. The suffix can be omitted if the size can be deduced from the arguments. `lea (%rsp, %rdx), %rax` (without the suffix) is valid and is the same instruction. Also `popq %rdi` and `pop %rdi` is valid. `pop %edi` is not valid at all in 64 bit code, suffix or no suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do in asm is limited by what the hardware can do.  Implicit vs. explicit operand-size in the source (suffix or not) doesn't change the machine code it will assemble to.

So the right question to ask is whether the hardware can do a 32-bit push in 64-bit mode?  No, it can't, therefore no asm source syntax exists that will get it to do exactly what you were trying to do with one instruction.

- [Does each PUSH instruction push a multiple of 8 bytes on x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305965/does-each-push-instruction-push-a-multiple-of-8-bytes-on-x64)
- [x86 Assembly pushl/popl don't work with "Error: suffix or operands invalid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485468/x86-assembly-pushl-popl-dont-work-with-error-suffix-or-operands-invalid/5486040#5486040)

That's why your assembler won't accept `pop %edi` or `popl %edi`.  Those are exactly equivalent because the 32-bit register implies DWORD (`l`) operand-size.  **The examples you saw of `popl` or `pop %edi` are for 32-bit mode,** where EDI is the full register instead of the low half of RDI, and that instruction is encodable.

You only need a size suffix when it's ambiguous, `mov $1, (%rdi)`.  Your assembler will give an error for that instead of guessing one of b/w/l/q.

But push is a bit special: `push $1` will default to a 64-bit push, even though `pushw $1` is possible.  [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127993/how-many-bytes-does-the-push-instruction-push-onto-the-stack-when-i-dont-specif)

Comment: you might want to explain that in 32 and 16 bit modes, push r32 is of course possible.