# Clang -fPIC compiler option explained

Tags: clang

Would someone please explain what the -fPIC option does.  I can't seem to find references to it, yet I've seen it in use.  I believe it has something to do with the memory allocation/space the executable will use, but would appreciate something more tangible.

Cheers,
Nap

Comment: Duplicate of the specified question. Even through it is for a different compiler, the explanation is the same because the flag does the same thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311515/gcc-fpic-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are the references you are looking for:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gccint/PIC.html