# What does the -fPIC compilation flag does?

Tags: shared-libraries, compiler-flags

What the -fpic flag does?
I want to install a library ([OpenSFM](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM)) and it is stated that it will need the Ceres Solver built and installed with the -fPIC compilation flag.

The problem is I already installed the Ceres Solver without the -fPIC flag and other library already depended on it. How can I solve this?

Comment: -fPIC makes Position Independent Code for shared libraries. Alternative to shared libraries is to use static linkage

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMake. `-fPIC` is no CMake flag, but a compiler one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good explaination for -fPIC can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311515/gcc-fpic-option).

I think the main question here is whether if you can still go ahead and install OpenSfM without rebuilding Ceres Solver. As far as I know, you can't.

The most straightforward thing you can do is rebuild Ceres Solver and reinstall the PIC version.

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=fPIC \
   -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC \ 
   -DSOMEOTHERARGUMENTSTHATYOUMIGHTHAVE
```

Let us know how it worked out for you. :)

Comment: If I uninstall the Ceres Solver, and then reinstall it, can it affect the other library that depends on it (in this case, it is OpenCV)?

Comment: Libraries compiled with -fPIC should still be compatible.

Comment: I had the same issue while installing eiskaltdcpp from the github source. The problem still remains after setting these flags in cmake command.