# Recompile with -fPIC

Tags: fpic

I write this command:

```
gcc drr.c -o drr -pthread -lcdsl -L./../synch_implementations -I./../synch_implementations
```

And I can't understand why I get this response:

```
usr/bin/ld: ./../synch_implementations/libcdsl.a(cdsl_queue_list.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
usr/bin/ld: ./../synch_implementations/libcdsl.a(cdsl_deque_list.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `cdsl_deque_list_lock_based_pthread_push_tail' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
usr/bin/ld: ./../synch_implementations/libcdsl.a(cdsl_lock.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `cdsl_pthread_lock_request' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
ollect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong?

Notes:

1)I use ubuntu (via VirtualBox).

2)I am very inexperienced, so probably this is not a very bright question.

Comment: *Position Independent Code*  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198826/what-does-the-fpic-compilation-flag-does

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:
When you compile ./../synch_implementations/libcdsl.a you need to add an extra "-fPIC" flag to produce position-independent-code (see comments above).

**Note**: 
The PIC flag is in general needed when producing library object code since it creates objects relative to a global offset table (GOT) which subsequently allows to link library objects with your code.