# is g++ -fPIC applicable for executable too in addition to shared libraries?

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries, fpic

I understand g++ -fPIC option as nicely explainjed in: [GCC -fPIC option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311515/gcc-fpic-option) 
I have many source files those are managed through `makefile` for build. It's difficult to segregate source files that is meant for being part of an executable or shared library. Can I used -fPIC option of g++ for any file that goes under compilation as:

```
g++ -c -fPIC ....
```

and later, if it is a shared library, link with `-shared`, otherwise without `-shared` for executable.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to build executables with `-fPIC` but this may result in performance penalties as compiler will make more conservative assumptions e.g. about inlining (to allow [runtime symbol interposition](http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/)). To produce position-independent executable, you'd better off using `-fPIE` flag (most modern distros e.g. [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PIE) build with it on by default now).

In any case, unless you really don't care about performance you'll need to compile your files twice, with different flags.

Answer (score -1):

**Can I used -fPIC option of g++ for any file that goes under compilation?**

Yes. If something such as an assembly file is given, it'll just have no effect.

**[ ... ] and later, if it is a shared library, link with -shared?**

Yes.

Comment: This answer does not mention potential consequences of using `-fPIC` (e.g. performance issues).