# Caffe error Ubuntu 16.04 with GPU /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libglog.a

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, caffe, ubuntu-16.04

Hello I am using caffe using Ubuntu 16.04 using GPU anyone have idea how to solve this error I tried by cannot figure out how to remove it. Firstly getting errors of OpenCV and Protobuf and now that I
 cannot understand . Also tried it with CPU only but won't work
thanks

```
 cmake ..
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so)
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.a)
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/local/bin/protoc
-- Found lmdb    (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so)
-- Found LevelDB (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so)
-- Found Snappy  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so)
-- -- CUDA is disabled. Building without it...
-- OpenCV found (/usr/local/share/OpenCV)
-- Found Atlas (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/libatlas.so)
-- NumPy ver. 1.12.0 found (include: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- 
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   1.0.0-rc5
--   Git               :   rc5-9-g793bd96-dirty
--   System            :   Linux
--   C++ compiler      :   /usr/bin/c++
--   Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -fPIC -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -fPIC -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Build type        :   Release
-- 
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   ON
--   BUILD_python      :   ON
--   BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs        :   ON
--   CPU_ONLY          :   ON
--   USE_OPENCV        :   ON
--   USE_LEVELDB       :   ON
--   USE_LMDB          :   ON
--   USE_NCCL          :   OFF
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF
-- 
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Atlas)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.58)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 2.5.0)
--   lmdb              :   Yes (ver. 0.9.17)
--   LevelDB           :   Yes (ver. 1.18)
--   Snappy            :   Yes (ver. 1.1.3)
--   OpenCV            :   Yes (ver. 3.2.0)
--   CUDA              :   No
-- 
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver. 2.7.12)
--   Libraries         :   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--   NumPy             :   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.0)
-- 
-- Documentaion:
--   Doxygen           :   No
--   config_file       :   
-- 
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   /home/khawar/caffe1/build/install
-- 
-- Configuring done
CMake Warning (dev) in src/caffe/CMakeLists.txt:
  Policy CMP0022 is not set: INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES defines the link
  interface.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0022" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Target "caffe" has an INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property which differs from
  its LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES properties.

  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES:

    proto;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so;$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a>;$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a>;-lpthread;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so;opencv_core;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;/usr/lib/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/libcblas.so;/usr/lib/libatlas.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so

  LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES:

    proto;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.a;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgflags.so;/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a;-lpthread;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblmdb.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so;opencv_core;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;/usr/lib/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/libcblas.so;/usr/lib/libatlas.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python.so

This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/khawar/caffe1/build
root@ntuser-Nuvo-4000-Series:/home/khawar/caffe1/build# make clean
root@ntuser-Nuvo-4000-Series:/home/khawar/caffe1/build# make all
[  1%] Running C++/Python protocol buffer compiler on /home/khawar/caffe1/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
Scanning dependencies of target proto
[  1%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/proto.dir/__/__/include/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc.o
[  1%] Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libproto.a
[  1%] Built target proto
Scanning dependencies of target caffe
[  1%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/common.cpp.o
[  1%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/internal_thread.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/dummy_data_layer.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/concat_layer.cpp.o
[  4%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/hinge_loss_layer.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/slice_layer.cpp.o
[  6%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/scale_layer.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cpp.o
[  7%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/dropout_layer.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/window_data_layer.cpp.o
[  9%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/base_conv_layer.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/batch_reindex_layer.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/loss_layer.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/data_layer.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/elu_layer.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/pooling_layer.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/flatten_layer.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/infogain_loss_layer.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/lrn_layer.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/threshold_layer.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/input_layer.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/base_data_layer.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/log_layer.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/inner_product_layer.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/neuron_layer.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/power_layer.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/cudnn_lrn_layer.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/multinomial_logistic_loss_layer.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/image_data_layer.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/softmax_layer.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/rnn_layer.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/eltwise_layer.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/bias_layer.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/relu_layer.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/filter_layer.cpp.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/reduction_layer.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/conv_layer.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/argmax_layer.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/absval_layer.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/prelu_layer.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/deconv_layer.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/spp_layer.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/crop_layer.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/accuracy_layer.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/lstm_unit_layer.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/bnll_layer.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/tile_layer.cpp.o
[ 41%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/recurrent_layer.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cpp.o
[ 43%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/cudnn_lcn_layer.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/lstm_layer.cpp.o
[ 44%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/exp_layer.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/tanh_layer.cpp.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/sigmoid_layer.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/batch_norm_layer.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/embed_layer.cpp.o
[ 47%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/split_layer.cpp.o
[ 49%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/reshape_layer.cpp.o
[ 49%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/parameter_layer.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/memory_data_layer.cpp.o
[ 52%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/silence_layer.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/mvn_layer.cpp.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/im2col_layer.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/blob.cpp.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/solvers/sgd_solver.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/solvers/rmsprop_solver.cpp.o
[ 56%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/solvers/nesterov_solver.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/solvers/adadelta_solver.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/solvers/adagrad_solver.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/solvers/adam_solver.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/parallel.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/solver.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layer.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/db.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/io.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/blocking_queue.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/upgrade_proto.cpp.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/benchmark.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/db_lmdb.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/math_functions.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/im2col.cpp.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/hdf5.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/db_leveldb.cpp.o
[ 69%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/signal_handler.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/insert_splits.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/cudnn.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/net.cpp.o
[ 72%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/data_transformer.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/syncedmem.cpp.o
[ 73%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layer_factory.cpp.o
[ 75%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libcaffe.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libglog.a(libglog_la-logging.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libglog.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:2717: recipe for target 'lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:272: recipe for target 'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@ntuser-Nuvo-4000-Series:/home/khawar/caffe1/build#
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is with the shared object creation with static object. Either `glog` should be a shared object (`glog.so`)  or `glog.a` should have been built with `-fPIC` option. If you want to understand  why `-fPIC` see [GCC -fPIC option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311515/gcc-fpic-option) . To solve this just install glog-dev using:

`sudo apt-get install libgoogle-glog-dev`