# When would you not want to compile with -fPIC?

Tags: gcc, fpic

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311515/gcc-fpic-option?noredirect=1&lq=1), compiling without `-fPIC` removes the ability for the code to be included in a library.  Why would someone want to do this?  Are there other reasons to compile without `-fPIC`?

Answer (score 3):

Because it is faster/smaller?  On some architectures, this can be significant.

Maybe you're building a firmware image that will be burned into ROM and thus fixed to a known address; so there is no reason to make it position independent.