# Doesn't PIC mean no relocations?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, elf

I'm building an ELF SO for bada on ARM using GCC. The compiler options include -fpic. Yet in the built file, when I do `readelf -r`, there's a whole lot of relocation records, of following types:

- R_ARM_RELATIVE
- R_ARM_REL32
- R_ARM_ABS32
- R_ARM_GLOB_DAT
- R_ARM_JUMP_SLOT

What am I misunderstanding here?

EDIT: from what I can see, the PIC implementation in the compiler doesn't use GOT. Instead, they use PC-relative addressing with stored constants being offsets from point of use to the symbol address; that's resolved by the linker. Like this, to read a global variable:

```
    ldr r12, OffsetToVar
PointOfUse:
    ldr r0, [r12, pc] 
# r0 now has the value of MyVar

#...

# At function's end...
OffsetToVar:
    .long MyVar-PointOfUse-8
# Compiler can't resolve this, since it doesn't know
# the address of MyVar, but linker can
```

Similar idea for cross-module function calls. When a project mixes ARM and Thumb code though, the latter may misfire. But I've worked around that.

Comment: Just a guess, do you access global data? If so the code may be a PIC, but the data is still bound to a possibly changing address?

Comment: PIC means Position Independent Code.  Instructions are chosen so that that chunk of code will execute properly even if loaded at an address space it was not linked for.

Comment: I will take a guess at what you want (but not an answer to the question).  See `-fixed-REG`, use [`-msingle-pic-base`](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/1999-07n/msg00573.html), and `-mpic-register` where your scheduler must set `r9` to point to global data.  So for instance, without an MMU you can run multiple code instances and replace `r9` as a pointer to globals for that task/thread/process.  This is a mechanism to avoid data relocation.  Also, it is common for the compiler/linker to emit relocations that are normally not needed.

Answer (score 6):

> Doesn't PIC mean no relocations?

No, it does *not*.

It just means no relocations against `.text` section (so the `.text` can be shared between multiple processes).

Comment: Is that true? "-fpic Generate position-independent code...  Such code accesses all constant addresses through a global offset table (GOT)." http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html

Comment: There is `-pic` and [`-pie`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/fpie-position-independent-executable-option-gcc-ld).  Really, it is going to depend on the `gcc` configuration.  I think this answer is correct for an *ARM Linux glibc* type environment.  For instance, there is a *static base* in the ARM EABI where all globals could reference to this register.  Also, sometime the *relocation* records don't actually do anything; Ie, the compiler/linker outputs an entry, but no actual fix-up is needed at load time.

Comment: Judging by offsets, there are some relocs in the text section, too. Is there a way to investigate further?

Comment: On x86-64, text relocations are allowed at least in PIE executables.  Maybe also in `gcc -shared` actual shared libraries.  (e.g. for `movabs rsi, offset symbol` to use a 64-bit immediate absolute, instead of the more efficient RIP-relative `lea`.)