# char *c="1234". Address stored in c is always the same

Tags: c, pointers

This was a question asked by an interviewer:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *c="123456";
    printf("%d\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

This piece of code always prints a fixed number (e.g. 13451392), no matter how many times you execute it. Why?

Comment: The question is "why would it change?"

Comment: Use `%p` to print a pointer.

Comment: Hint: on a system that supports this (Linux for sure, I *think* also OSX) compile with `gcc -pie -fpie` and the value printed *will* change on every execution.  Here's [an explanation of what those options do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/fpie-position-independent-executable-option-gcc-ld).  Think about what that must mean.

Comment: Your title asks about the "address of `c`". Your program prints the *value* of `c`, which happens to be a pointer (i.e., an address). And [dasblinkenlight's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25457552/827263) shows the correct way to print that value. It's likely (but by no means certain) that the *address* of the pointer object `c` will also be the same; you can use `printf("&c = %p\n", (void*)&c);` to find out.

Comment: @Zack: Pointing out an error is not "fixating" on it -- and it probably wasn't obvious to the OP. (Good edit, BTW.)

Comment: "Address stored in c is always the same"  "Always" is a long time.  I doubt this was tried for that long.

Answer (score 4):

Your code contains undefined behavior: printing a pointer needs to be done using `%p` format specifier, and only after converting it to `void*`:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)c);
```

This would produce a system-dependent number, which may or may not be the same on different platforms.

The reason that it is fixed on your platform is probably that the operating system always loads your executable into the same spot of virtual memory (which may be mapped to different areas of physical memory, but your program would never know). String literal, which is part of the executable, would end up in the same spot as well, so the printout would be the same all the time.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the character string "123456" is a static constant in memory, and when the .exe is loaded, it always goes into the same memory location.

What `c` is (or rather what it contains) is the memory address of that character string which, as I said, is always at the same location. If you print the address as a decimal number, you see the address, in decimal.

Of course, as @dasblinkenlight said, you should print it as a pointer, because different machines/languages have different conventions about the size of pointers versus the size of ints.

Comment: Size is not the only issue. Even if `sizeof (int) == sizeof (int*)`, using `"%d"` to print a pointer value still has undefined behavior. (For example, pointers and integers might be passed as arguments using different mechanisms.)

Comment: @Keith: Yes I noticed, thanks. Yeah I know the behavior is undefined, but with a newbie I don't want to confuse him by splitting hairs.

Comment: I wouldn't want to encourage newbies to think that using `"%d"` to print a pointer value is ok if you happen to know that they have the same size. And `"%p"` will print the address in a more sensible format (often, but not always, hexadecimal).

Comment: @Keith: From my teaching days, I always found the basic ideas of programming much easier to get across if people can think of a pointer as a variable that contains an address, and an address is nothing but a number, that just happens to mean where something is in memory. Once they have a concrete foundation, then we can get abstract and say a pointer is really something different from a number. If I say that at the beginning, it's just confusing. They want to know what it *is*, not what it *isn't*.

Comment: Ah, but pointers *aren't* numbers, though they share some of their properties. I see too many C programmers who have never unlearned the idea that pointers are just numbers. (For example, adding two pointers make no sense.) The book "Accelerated C++" takes an interesting approach to this. It introduces containers and iterators early on and shows what you can do with them. Then, in a later chapter, it introduces arrays as a kind of low-level container, and pointers as a kind of low-level iterator. Obviously that's not directly applicable to C, but I like the idea.

Comment: Then again, I don't have much in the way of teaching experience; perhaps your approach is better. And undoubtedly different approaches are better for different students.

Comment: @Keith: You have to build on what students already know. They know arithmetic, so if you start with a simple model of memory as a set of numbered mailboxes, and a computer as a really stupid mailman doing what some of the numbers in the mailboxes are telling him, they get it. Then you can introduce higher-level ideas and they have a grounding. Much later you can introduce discrete mathematics like groups, rings, or lattices where a datatype is a really abstract set with operations on it, which is much easier to get if they can always relate it back to a concrete model.

Answer (score 1):

Most executable file formats have an option to tell the OS loader at which [*virtual address*](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/F06/slides/cs350_D.pdf) to load the executable, For example [PE format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) used by Windows has [`ImageBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) field for this and usually sets to `0x00400000` for applications.

When the loader first load the executable, it tries load it at that address, if it's not used, it load it at it, which is mostly true, but if it's used. It load it at different address given by the system.

The case here is that the offset to your `"12345"` in the data section is the same, and OS loads the image base at the same base address, so you always get the same virtual address, base + offset.

But this is not always the case, one for the given reason above, the base address may be used, alot of Windows DLLs compile using MSVC sets their base address to `0x10000000`, so only one or none is actually loaded at that address.

Another case is when there is address space randomization [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR), security feature, if it is supported and enabled by the system, MSVC has the linker option [`/DYNAMICBASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384887.aspx), the system will ignore the specified image base and will give you different random address on its own.

Two things to conclude:

- You should not depend on this behavior, the system can load your program at any address and thus you will give different address.
- Use `%p` for printing address, on some systems, for example, `int` is 4 bytes and pointers are 8 bytes, part of you address will be chopped.