# How does the Linux kernel determine ld.so's load address?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64, elf, dynamic-linking

I know that the dynamic linker uses `mmap()` to load libraries. I guess it is the kernel who loads both the executable and its `.interp`reter into the same address space, but how does it determine where? I noticed that `ld.so`'s load address with ASLR disabled is `0x555555554000` (on x86_64) — where does this address come from? I tried following `do_execve()`'s code path, but it is too ramified for me not to be confused as hell.

Comment: Imagining from scratch, it seems like the address must either be chosen by the kernel or encoded in the file.  You looked for evidence in the kernel, have you tried looking in the file?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I dissected both the executable and the dynamic linker — there's nothing that looks remotely like this address.

Comment: Why do you ask? Why do you care? Please edit your question to motivate it? Are you coding a new dynamic linker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read more about [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), in particular [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), and about the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall.

An ELF file may contain an interpreter.  [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) mentions:

> `PT_INTERP`   The array element specifies the location and
>      size of a null-terminated pathname to invoke
>     as an interpreter.  This segment type is
>      meaningful only for executable files (though
>      it may occur for shared objects).  However it
>    may not occur more than once in a file.  If
>     it is present, it must precede any loadable
>   segment entry.

That interpreter is practically almost always [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) (e.g. with GNU [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)), more precisely (on my Debian/Sid) `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. If you compile [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) then build some software with it you'll get a different interpreter, `/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1`. That ELF interpreter is the [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker).

The [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall is using that interpreter:

> If the executable is a dynamically linked ELF executable, the
>          interpreter named in the `PT_INTERP` segment is used to load the needed
>          shared libraries.  This interpreter is typically `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`
>          for binaries linked with glibc.

See also Levine's book on [*Linkers and loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/), and [Drepper's paper: *How To Write Shared Libraries*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Notice that `execve` is also handling the shebang (i.e. first line starting with `#!`); see the *Interpreter scripts* section of [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). BTW, for ELF binaries, `execve` is doing the *equivalent* of [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on some segments.

Read also about [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html), [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5..html) & [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). Type `cat /proc/self/maps` in your shell.

<sup>(I guess, but I am not sure, that the 0x555555554000 address is in the ELF program header of your executable, or perhaps of `ld-linux.so`; it might also come from the kernel, since 0x55555555 seems to appear in the kernel source code)</sup>