# How is the address of the text section of a PIE executable determined in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, glibc, aslr, position-independent-code

First I tried to reverse engineer it a bit:

```
printf '
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    puts("hello world");
}
' > main.c
gcc -std=c99 -pie -fpie -ggdb3 -o pie main.c
echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
readelf -s ./pie | grep -E 'main$'
gdb -batch -nh \
  -ex 'set disable-randomization off' \
  -ex 'start' -ex 'info line' \
  -ex 'start' -ex 'info line' \
  -ex 'set disable-randomization on' \
  -ex 'start' -ex 'info line' \
  -ex 'start' -ex 'info line' \
  ./pie \
;
```

Output:

```
64: 000000000000063a    23 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 main
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello world");
Line 4 of "main.c" starts at address 0x5575f5fd263e <main+4> and ends at 0x5575f5fd264f <main+21>.
Temporary breakpoint 2 at 0x5575f5fd263e: file main.c, line 4.

Temporary breakpoint 2, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello world");
Line 4 of "main.c" starts at address 0x55e3fbc9363e <main+4> and ends at 0x55e3fbc9364f <main+21>.
Temporary breakpoint 3 at 0x55e3fbc9363e: file main.c, line 4.

Temporary breakpoint 3, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello world");
Line 4 of "main.c" starts at address 0x55555555463e <main+4> and ends at 0x55555555464f <main+21>.
Temporary breakpoint 4 at 0x55555555463e: file main.c, line 4.

Temporary breakpoint 4, main () at main.c:4
4           puts("hello world");
Line 4 of "main.c" starts at address 0x55555555463e <main+4> and ends at 0x55555555464f <main+21>.
```

which indicates that it is `0x555555554000` + random offset + `63e`.

But then I tried to grep the Linux kernel and glibc source code for `555555554` and there were no hits.

Which part of which code calculates that address?

I came across this while answering: [What is the -fPIE option for position-independent executables in gcc and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld/51308031#51308031)

Comment: Basile had same guess in 2015: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29856596/196561 "*since 0x55555555 seems to appear in the kernel source code*", but now I can't find 55555555 in linux kernel

Answer (score 8):

Some *Internet search* of 0x555555554000 gives hints: there were problems with ThreadSanitizer https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual

> Q: When I run the program, it says: FATAL: ThreadSanitizer can not mmap the shadow memory (something is mapped at 0x555555554000 < 0x7cf000000000). What to do? You need to enable ASLR:
>
> ```
>  $ echo 2 >/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
> ```
>
> This may be fixed in future kernels, see https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=66721
>   ...
>
> ```
>  $ gdb -ex 'set disable-randomization off' --args ./a.out
> ```

and https://lwn.net/Articles/730120/ "Stable kernel updates." Posted Aug 7, 2017 20:40 UTC (Mon) by hmh (subscriber) https://marc.info/?t=150213704600001&r=1&w=2
 (https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9886105/, [commit c715b72c1ba4](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c715b72c1ba406f133217b509044c38d8e714a37))

> Moving the x86_64 and arm64 PIE base from 0x555555554000 to 0x000100000000
>   broke AddressSanitizer. This is a partial revert of:
>
> - [commit eab09532d400](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/eab09532d40090698b05a07c1c87f39fdbc5fab5) ("binfmt_elf: use ELF_ET_DYN_BASE only for PIE") (https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9807325/ https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/6/21/560)
> - [commit 02445990a96e](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/02445990a96e60a67526510d8b00f7e3d14101c3) ("arm64: move ELF_ET_DYN_BASE to 4GB / 4MB") (https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9807319/)

Reverted code was:

> ```
> b/arch/arm64/include/asm/elf.h
>  /*
>   * This is the base location for PIE (ET_DYN with INTERP) loads. On
> - * 64-bit, this is raised to 4GB to leave the entire 32-bit address
> + * 64-bit, this is above 4GB to leave the entire 32-bit address   * space open for things that want to use the area for 32-bit pointers.   */
> -#define ELF_ET_DYN_BASE      0x100000000UL
> +#define ELF_ET_DYN_BASE      (2 * TASK_SIZE_64 / 3)
>
>
> +++ b/arch/x86/include/asm/elf.h
>  /*
>   * This is the base location for PIE (ET_DYN with INTERP) loads. On
> - * 64-bit, this is raised to 4GB to leave the entire 32-bit address
> + * 64-bit, this is above 4GB to leave the entire 32-bit address
>   * space open for things that want to use the area for 32-bit pointers.
>   */
>  #define ELF_ET_DYN_BASE      (mmap_is_ia32() ? 0x000400000UL : \
> -                       0x100000000UL)
> +                       (TASK_SIZE / 3 * 2))
> ```

So, 0x555555554000 is related with [`ELF_ET_DYN_BASE` macro](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/ident/ELF_ET_DYN_BASE) (referenced in [fs/binfmt_elf.c for `ET_DYN` as not randomized `load_bias`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L987)) and for x86_64 and arm64 it is like 2/3 of TASK_SIZE. When there is no `CONFIG_X86_32`, x86_64 has TASK_SIZE of [2^47 - one page in `arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.140/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L736)

```
/*
 * User space process size. 47bits minus one guard page.  The guard
 * page is necessary on Intel CPUs: if a SYSCALL instruction is at
 * the highest possible canonical userspace address, then that
 * syscall will enter the kernel with a non-canonical return
 * address, and SYSRET will explode dangerously.  We avoid this
 * particular problem by preventing anything from being mapped
 * at the maximum canonical address.
 */
#define TASK_SIZE_MAX   ((1UL << 47) - PAGE_SIZE)
```

Older versions:

```
/*
 * User space process size. 47bits minus one guard page.
 */
#define TASK_SIZE_MAX   ((1UL << 47) - PAGE_SIZE)
```

Newer versions also have support of [5level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_5-level_paging) with [`__VIRTUAL_MASK_SHIFT` of 56 bit](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/ident/__VIRTUAL_MASK_SHIFT) -  [`v4.17/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L867) (but [don't want to use it before enabled by user](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10046207/) + [commit b569bab78d8d ".. Not all user space is ready to handle wide addresses")](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b569bab78d8d)).

So, 0x555555554000 is rounded down (by [`load_bias = ELF_PAGESTART(load_bias - vaddr);`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L1001), vaddr is zero) from the formula **(2^47-1page)*(2/3)** (or 2^56 for [larger systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_5-level_paging)):

```
$ echo 'obase=16; (2^47-4096)/3*2'| bc -q
555555554AAA
$ echo 'obase=16; (2^56-4096)/3*2'| bc -q
AAAAAAAAAAA000
```

Some history of 2/3 * TASK_SIZE:

- [commit 9b1bbf6ea9b2 "use ELF_ET_DYN_BASE only for PIE"](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=9b1bbf6ea9b2b596ba271bec23b93c48181ad896) has usefull comments: "*The ELF_ET_DYN_BASE position was originally intended to keep loaders away from ET_EXEC binaries ...*"
- Don't overflow 32bits with 2*TASK_SIZE ["[uml-user] [PATCH] x86, UML: fix integer overflow in ELF_ET_DYN_BASE", 2015](https://sourceforge.net/p/user-mode-linux/mailman/message/33634472/) and ["ARM: 8320/1: fix integer overflow in ELF_ET_DYN_BASE", 2015](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/diff/?id=c5528d2a0edcbbc3ceba739ec70133e2594486c4):

> Almost all arches define ELF_ET_DYN_BASE as 2/3 of TASK_SIZE. Though
>   it seems that some architectures do this in a wrong way. The problem
>   is that 2*TASK_SIZE may overflow 32-bits so the real ELF_ET_DYN_BASE
>   becomes wrong. Fix this overflow by dividing TASK_SIZE prior to
>   multiplying: `(TASK_SIZE / 3 * 2)`

- Same in 4.x, 3.y, 2.6.z, (where is davej-history git repo? [archive](https://archive.org/details/git-history-of-linux) and [at or.cz](http://repo.or.cz/davej-history.git)) 2.4.z, ...  [added in 2.1.54](http://repo.or.cz/davej-history.git/blobdiff/6696fcb6cfcf1fe38ed7f56a87790e4ed6e90ee7..12e35fae7bd6654942b7b38010c260d411c036e2:/include/asm-i386/elf.h) of 06-Sep-1997

> ```
> diff --git a/include/asm-i386/elf.h b/include/asm-i386/elf.h
> +/* This is the location that an ET_DYN program is loaded if exec'ed.  Typical
> +   use of this is to invoke "./ld.so someprog" to test out a new version of
> +   the loader.  We need to make sure that it is out of the way of the program
> +   that it will "exec", and that there is sufficient room for the brk.  */
> +
> +#define ELF_ET_DYN_BASE         (2 * TASK_SIZE / 3)
> ```

Comment: PIE should randomize every run, am I wrong? or it's the aslr only doing it?