# gcc: Set vaddr of sections

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, elf

I have code that needs to `mmap` an external file into a particular memory range.  How can I tell the linker to map my host code into a *different* range? That is, how can I tell the linker "avoid putting any section at vaddr 0x40000"?

I am doing `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE`, and want to ensure that this doesn't fail; e.g. no collision.

Linux, gcc (for C and for linking), nasm (for asm), 64 bit

Comment: Easiest way is to make a PIE executable, `gcc -fPIE -pie`.  That gets ASLRed to somewhere near the lower 1/3rd of the user-space virtual-address range, far from `0x40000`, although it's possible to customize the default load address.  But if you're making a non-PIE executable, the image base address is fixed by the linker (*not* relocatable at run-time), usually at `0x400000`.  (one more zero than your target address).  You can set BSS, text, rodata, and data segment bases explicitly with `-Tbss=0x500000` and so on, but you have to know how much room to leave between each one; not recommended.

Comment: PIE is great.  Is there a way to explicitly specify (I guess to the runtime loader): Do not load this PIE into region X, because I will want to mmap something into X?

Comment: Not that I know of.  See [How is the address of the text section of a PIE executable determined in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51343596) - the ASLR base address is hard-coded as `ELF_ET_DYN_BASE      (2 * TASK_SIZE_64 / 3)`. (At least before support for PML5 57-bit virt addrs was added.)  So I was mis-remembering, there isn't a sysctl for this; you'd have to recompile the kernel to change the load address.  ASLR doesn't use a huge number of bits, so it's always around `0x000055...`  (Run `cat /proc/self/maps` a few times)

Comment: The only surefire way is to use a custom linker script that places a dummy section at the desired memory range, preventing anything else from being loaded there.  But that's kind of fragile to get right.