# Compile Python code to statically linked executable with Cython

Tags: python, gcc, linker, cython

I have a pure Python script that I would like to distribute to systems with unkown Python configuration. Therefore, I would like to compile the Python code to a stand-alone executable.

I run `cython --embed ./foo.py` without problems giving `foo.c`. Then, I run

```
gcc $(python3-config --cflags) $(python3-config --ldflags) ./foo.c
```

where `python3-config --cflags` gives

```
-I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/python3.5m  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-MLq5fN/python3.5-3.5.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

and `python3-config --ldflags` gives

```
-L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

This way I obtain a dynamically linked executable that runs without a problem. `ldd a.out` yields

```
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcd57fd000)
 libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 (0x00007fda76823000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fda76603000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fda763fb000)
 libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fda761f3000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fda75eeb000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fda75b4b000)
 libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fda7591b000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fda756fb000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fda77103000)
```

Now, I try to add the option `-static` to gcc, but this results in an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol `strcmp' with pointer equality in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(strcmp.o)' can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and relink with -pie
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I checked that all shared libraries given by ldd are also installed as static libraries.

So, is this some incompatibility with the options given by python3-config?

Comment: truly guessing `-export-dynamic` looks like a suspect?

Comment: `-export-dynamic` is about the "dynamic symbol table" (according to gcc documentation). I don't know what this is. Anyway, removing this yields an error: `/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-Wl,-O1'`. gcc won't recognize the `-Wl` options anymore. Without these however, I get `File format not recognized`.

Comment: I think `-Xlinker -export-dynamic` isone flag - (XLinker forwards the flag to the linker) try removing as a whole?

Comment: Removing these two flags is possible, indeed. It gives a functioning executable. However, adding `-static` results in a huge number of errors of the type `undefined reference to 'PyObject_Call'`.

Comment: How is your linker command line looks like? `foo.o` should come before the libraries for the static linkage.

Comment: @ead I'm not sure I understand your question. The command I enter is `gcc $(python3-config --cflags) $(python3-config --ldflags) -static ./foo.c`.

Comment: gcc is only a front-end which bundles different steps together: code->assembler->object-files->executables. You can see what happens under the hood when you add `-v` (verbose) to the gcc-command-line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The experienced problems are obviously from the linker (gcc started a linker under the hood, to see it - just start gcc with `-v` - in verbose mode). So let's start with a short reminder how the linkage process works:

The linker keeps the names of all symbols it needs to resolve. In the beginning it is only the symbol `main`. What happens, when linker inspects a library?

1. If it is a static library, the linker looks at every object file in this library, and if this object files defines some looked for symbols, the whole object file is included (which means some symbols becomes resolved, but some further new unresolved symbols can be added). Linker might need to pass multiple times over a static library.
2. If it is a shared library, it is viewed by the linker as a library consisting out of a single huge object file (after all, we have to load this library at the run time and don't have to pass multiple times over and over to prune unused symbols): If there is at least one needed symbol the whole library is "linked" (not really the linkage happens at the run-time, this is a kind of a dry-run), if not - the whole library is discarded and never looked again at.

For example if you link with:

```
gcc -L/path -lpython3.x <other libs> foo.o
```

you will get a problem, no matter whether `python3.x` is a shared or a static lib: when the linker sees it, it looks only for the symbol `main`, but this symbol is not defined in the python-lib, so it the python-lib is discarded and never looked again at. Only when the linker sees the object-file `foo.o`, it realizes, that the whole Python-Symbols are needed, but now it is already too late.

There is a simple rule to handle this problem: put the object files first! That means:

```
gcc -L/path  foo.o -lpython3.x <other libs>
```

Now the linker knows what it needs from the python-lib, when it first sees it.

There are other ways to achieve a similar result.

A) Let the linker to reiterate a group of archives as long as at least one new symbol definition was added per sweep:

```
gcc -L/path --Wl,-start-group -lpython3.x <other libs> foo.o -Wl,-end-group
```

Linker-options `-Wl,-start-group` and `-Wl,-end-group` says to linker iterate more than once over this group of archives, so the linker has a second chance (or more) to include symbols. This option can lead to longer linkage time.

B) Switching on the option `--no-as-needed` will lead to a shared library (and only shared library) being linked in, no matter whether in this library defined symbols are needed or not.

```
gcc -L/path -Wl,-no-as-needed -lpython3.x -Wl,-as-needed <other libs> foo.o
```

Actually, the default ld-behavior is `--no-as-needed`, but the gcc-frontend calls ld with option `--as-needed`, so we can restore the behavior by adding `-no-as-needed` prior to the python-library and then switch it off again.

---

Now to your problem of statical linking. I don't think it is advisable to use static versions of all standard libraries (all above glibc), what you should probably do is to link only the python-library statically.

The rules of the linkage are simple: per default the linker tries to open a shared version of the library first and than the static version. I.e. for the library `libmylib` and paths `A` and `B`, i.e.

```
 -L/A -L/B lmylib
```

it tries to open libraries in the following order:

```
A/libmylib.so
A/libmylib.a
B/libmylib.so
B/libmylib.a
```

Thus if the folder `A` has only a static version, so this static version is used (no matter whether there is a shared version in folder `B`).

Because it is quite opaque which library is really used - it depends on the setup of your system, usually one would switch on the logging of the linker via `-Wl,-verbose` to trouble-shoot.

By using the option `-Bstatic` one can enforce the usage of the static version of a library:

```
gcc  foo.o -L/path -Wl,-Bstatic -lpython3.x -Wl,-Bdynamic <other libs>  -Wl,-verbose -o foo
```

Notable thing:

1. `foo.o` is linked before the libraries.
2. switch the static-mode off, directly after the python-library, so other libraries are linked dynamically.

And now:

```
 gcc <cflags> L/paths foo.c -Wl,-Bstatic -lpython3.X -Wl,-Bdynamic <other libs> -o foo -Wl,-verbose
...
attempt to open path/libpython3.6m.a succeeded
...
ldd foo shows no dependency on python-lib
./foo
It works!
```

---

And yes, if you link against static `glibc` (I don't recommend), you will need to delete `-Xlinker -export-dynamic` from the command line.

The executable compiled without `-Xlinker -export-dynamic` will not be able to load some of c-extension which depend on this property of the executable to which they are loaded with `ldopen`.

---

**Possible issues due to implicit `-pie` option.**

[Recent versions of gcc](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/ppc64el/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#pie-is-now-default) build  with [`pie`-option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2463150/5769463) per default. Often/sometimes, older python versions where build with an older gcc-version, thus `python-config --cflags` would miss the now necessary  `-no-pie`, as it was not needed back then. In this case the linker will produce an error message like:

> relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `XXXXX' can not be used when
> making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC

In this case, `-no-pie` option should be added to  `<cflags>`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed and interesting answer. My command line now reads `gcc $(python3-config --cflags) -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib ./foo.c -Wl,-Bstatic -lpython3.5m -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -o foo -Wl,-verbose`. However, I still get this huge number of 'undefined reference' errors, for instance `/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(zlibmodule.o): In function 'PyInit_zlib':
(.text+0x1ad): undefined reference to 'zlibVersion'`.

Comment: @phlegmax I don't know what is went wrong on your system with finding all dependencies. But obviously you need to  add `-lzlib` to the libraries. Actually, the list of all needed libraries is given in your question (the result of `ldd a.out`)