# How to create a Windows executable that embeds the Python interpreter using Cython

Tags: python, windows, cython, static-linking

I try to create an executable using Cython with embedded Python ([look here](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython)). I can find examples doing this on Linux, but not on Windows. The only Windows example I can find results in an executable that calls the python dll ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can%20-cython-compile-to-an-exe)). But this is not what I am looking for. I want a standalone executable that does not call the python dll.

Below what I did:

First the program (hello.py):

```
print("hello")
```

I run Cython with the --embed option in an anaconda prompt:

```
cython hello.py --embed
```

This results in a c file with a main function (hello.c).

Then set the appropriate environment variables:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

Then compile and link this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe"  /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\Anaconda3_5.2.0\include -Ic:\Anaconda3_5.2.0\PC /Tchello.c /link /OUT:"test.exe" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3_5.2.0\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Anaconda3_5.2.0\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64"
```

This results in a small (19 KB) executable (test.exe).

To run this set the PYTHONPATH

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Anaconda3_5.2.0
```

and call the program

```
test.exe
```

This runs whitout any problems, but Python is not embedded as it calls python36.dll. I suppose the compiling and linking must be done differently, but I don't know how. Does anybody know how to create a windows executable that embeds the Python interpreter using Cython? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by " but Python is not embedded" exactly? The program doesn't run something different?

Comment: @ead I think what OP means is "Python is not statically linked into the executable"

Comment: "embeded Python" doesn't mean the Python-library is statically linked. The first question, do you have static python library in your distribution? Here is a question about static linking on Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48796014/5769463 which is different than on Windows...

Comment: DavidW is right. But am I misunderstanding the meaning of embedded in https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython?

Comment: @ead By the way this is a good idea! Is there a way to statically link Python-library (python38.dll and even vcruntime140.dll etc. and maybe all the DLLs [in the list given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62392087/1422096)) on  Windows when using `cython --embed`?

Comment: Something else @ead (I know you have high Cython knowledge from your other answers to my other questions :)), do you have an idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73027842/cython-embed-on-windows?

Comment: this question seems like a duplicate of:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796014/compile-python-code-to-statically-linked-executable-with-cython?noredirect=1&lq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581784/can-cython-compile-to-an-exe?noredirect=1&lq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390978/minimal-set-of-files-required-to-distribute-an-embed-cython-compiled-code-and-ma?noredirect=1&lq=1