Script to check if all the needed python libraries including python are downloaded
I have made a pure Python program with a few libraries which I want to convert to an exe file. The problem is that I have to download it later to a few other computers and they might not have python or the needed libraries installed.
My question is - when the exe file is started (for the first time or not) i want to check if the needed components (library and python version from requirements.txt) are present on the computer and if they are not, i need them to be downloaded.
Any help?

You may wish to search about how to statically link a Python program to an executable. This search immediately pulled up a previous SO question for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796014/

@Chris , thank you, i will check it out

Have you tried PyInstaller? It makes fully self-contained, portable executables from Python programs.

While this question is worded differently, I think you're after the same end goal as it: How can I make a Python script standalone executable to run without any dependency?

you may put every import in own try/except and use module pip in except to install missing module. e.g. pip.main(['install' , 'pandas']). But I don't know if it will work when Python is in .exe (created with PyInstaller). It may need to add module pip to .exe. But I think it would be better to use pip install -r requirements.txt only once.

While creating an executable containing an embedded version of Python is possible, it is relatively complicated and not generally done.
Instead, you can use standard Python packaging tools to package both your code and any dependencies it needs. There are multiple backend build frameworks in Python. The official Python Packaging Tutorial makes use of Hatchling and a pyproject.toml file. The file defines the entry point to your application, any dependencies it needs, what version of Python it requires, and other characteristics.
Once ready, you will run python -m build to create distribution bundles. The bundles typically create both an archived file of your build and a wheel file. You can either copy the wheel file directly to other machines or you can upload it to either the public PyPi repository (if you want to make your application available to anyone) or a private repository.
Either way, client machines that need to use your application will run something like python -m pip install <path_to_wheel_file>. That will download and install any needed dependencies, However, the correct Python version will need to be installed on the system first.
If you really need to have Python version detection available, then one simpler solution would be to create an install script that checks the python version, and then attempts to automatically install it if not present. Since you mentioned a .exe file I assume you are only concerned with Windows installs.
To find out if Python is installed and on the search path, you can use the PowerShell command Get-Command python. To check for the version, run python --version.
If you need to automatically install Python, you can use a Windows package manager called Chocolatey. Chocolatey itself must be installed (but that can be done entirely with a Powershell command, no browser or external download is needed). Chocolatey has non-interactive installs for all Python versions (e.g. choco install python310). You can search for packages at https://community.chocolatey.org/packages. Depending on how Chocolatey is configured and the package you are installing, you may need to change the Powershell execution policy and/or run it in an elevated command prompt.
You could combine all of the above into a single PowerShell script that:

Checks for the presence of the correct Python version.
If not present, installs Chocolately, then uses it to install the correct version of Python
Installs your application from either a wheel file or downloads it from a PiPy repository.
Exectues your application after it is installed.


That is the best approach for, say, libraries and utilities designed to be used in a Python environment. It sounds like they want more of a "package it and forget it" portable executable, which is more the sort of thing PyInstaller (and Nuitka and a few others) do.

my idea is if the app is used on a new PC, when the exe is pressed to run -> first checks if all the needed components (libraries, python, etc) are downloaded and then to run the main program.
