# .data' can not be used when making a PIE object

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I compiled a Asm program in base x86-64, when i was trying to linked object files by gcc i got the following error:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
```

So i want to know what is PIE object? (I coudln't find a clearly explain in internet)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the -fPIE option for position-independent executables in gcc and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld)