# Intel Pin Modifying Instruction Addresses

Tags: x86, instrumentation, intel-pin

I am trying to do some instruction analysis of an executable-binary using Intel Pin-tool instrumentation.

Upon analyzing the executed instructions in my Pin-tool, I am observing that the instruction address (program counter) value-range received is very different from what I otherwise observe when analyze the disassembly of the compiled code using `objdump -d -S <binary>`. I am testing it on the standard Linux `/bin/ls` executable-binary.

As per my understanding, Pin modifies the original binary to put its own "hooks" to gather execution related information which invoke call-backs in our desired Pin-tool for analysis. So, this naturally should lead to the actually executed binary as being different from the original. Unfortunately, I do not know other under-the-hood stuff about Pin.

I was wondering if there was any way to preserve the original code layout, or obtain some correspondence between the old binary and new binary instruction addresses?

Answer (score 2):

Modern distros use PIE executables that are ELF shared objects that get relocated at runtime.  `objdump` only shows you addresses relative to the image base.  [What is the -fPIE option for position-independent executables in gcc and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld) and [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)

You can disable ASLR like GDB does so it's always relocated to the *same* place, like `0x55555...`, but it still won't match the `objdump` address.

You could I think use `objdump --adjust-vma=offset` to relocate your disassembly.

**Or you could build non-PIE executables with `gcc -no-pie -fno-pie -O3`** so objdump will know the real run-time address of every instruction.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the problem is with the placement of binary images (Note that `Pin` analysis instructions do **not** change user visible behavior of the program, so aggressively. The main effects are on performance and things such as caching). For example, your `glibc` image is placed at an address which is different from the address when the program is run in `Pin`. If that is the case, firstly, you should add an **image callback**, like this:

```
...
VOID callbackFn(IMG img, VOID *v)
{...}
...
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ...
   IMG_AddInstrumentFunction(callbackFn, 0);
   ...
}
...
```

The callback function (i.e., `callbackFn()`) is called at each image load time. In the callback body, you can use `IMG_LowAddress(img)` to obtain the load address of each image at runtime. There are also functions such as `IMG_Name(img)` and `IMG_IsMainExecutable(img)` which may be helpful. Now, you know the start address of the binary image, which is `B`.

You want to find the address for a function `foo()` in the image, at runtime. Suppose that, `objdump` says it is at address `A` from the beginning of the binary image. In order to find the runtime address of `foo()`, you only need to add `A` to `B`. In other words, `foo()` is located at `A + B`, at runtime.

P.S.: Be careful about symbolic links when parsing image names. You can use [this function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) to get over the problem.