# Is there any method to find out a static library is compiled with -fPIC flag

Tags: c++, static-libraries, fpic

I have a bunch of static libraries in my hand, which all have two versions -- 32bit and 64bit.
  When I use these static libraries to compile into a shared library, weird things
happened: 
  1. I use 64bit static libraries to compile a 64bit shared library, everything works well;
  2. I use 32bit static libraries to compile a 32bit shared library, ld tells me that the [text section is not shareable].

So, I guess that 32bit static libraries don't use -fPIC flag, but my colleague tells me he dit add the flag.
  But I still suspect that, so is there a way to find out whether the static library do add the -fPIC flag.
  PS: I know use readelf or objdump may get some clues, but is there a better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell, with something like objdump, if an object file has been built with -fPIC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340402/how-can-i-tell-with-something-like-objdump-if-an-object-file-has-been-built-wi)

Answer (score -1):

I believe, if you are using linux, you can check out the output of `file`

```
file myLib.so
file myLib.a
```

The output should inform you if the library was compiled with -fPIC

Comment: well, I tried. I build  test.o and test_pic.o by myself, but the output is all:  ELF 64-bit LSB  relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped

Comment: Do you run `file` for the objects, or the library?

Comment: I run for the objects file.   If run for the library, libtest.a for example, the output will only tell : 'archive file'.

Comment: Hmm... Try running for `libtest.so`. It should say more than that. `libtest.a` is indeed an archive of object files, so that's why `file` reports it as such.

Comment: Well, what I need is identify a static library.   So, this may don't work.

Comment: Oh, okay,, Sorry this didn't work, best of luck finding your answer :)